# Group result and display count in a view

Tags: 7, views

I want to create a view and group the result like display only 1 record and along with it display the count of the similar records along with it. Can i do it in views with out writing any code. i.e. result should look like

```
Football (3)

Tennis (6)

Cricket (4)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a Contextual Filter for whichever field you want to sort off of. If the filter value is not in the url it will display a list like you have above.

[image: image of contextual filter using "number of records"]

Comment: I don't want any sorting to be done. Just grouping and count to be displayed

Comment: Sorry, it is late. The "Display a summary" is what will do the grouping and counting. The "Sort order" will just be by 'most first'.

Comment: Nice and simple :) I found this easiest to implement, but the summary itself is a bit inflexible.

Answer (score 6):

My example is based on 1 Content Type and 1 field (City).

1. **FIELDS**. Add 2 same fields in fields area you wanna group and show counter.
2. **FORMAT**. Group by required field
   [image]
3. **PAGER**. Set 0 in Pager area.
4. **ADVANCED**.
   Enable aggregation in advanced settings
   [image]
5. **COUNT**. Enabled 'count' for second field (which is not used to group)
   [image]
6. **Sorting**. Set sorting as your group field.

**FINAL**

This is how looks my view
[image]

**RESULT**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I need this feature  and see this Q&A, I try it but not getting desire result, keeping on my search and I found [Views Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) . this is exactly I need and good solution for future guys that search for this feature.

> As the Views and Views Calc modules rely on the database to perform
>   aggregation, you only have limited options at your disposal. As the
>   great Merlin himself said: "You can't aggregate a PHP expression in
>   the database.  :/ ". That's where Views Aggregator Plus comes in. In
>   addition to what Views and Views Calc do, this module:
>
> ```
> enumerates group members
> produces tallies, i.e. textual histograms
> aggregates on Views PHP code-snippet evalutations
> can filter out result rows on regexp patterns
> gives you sorting on Views' Math expressions
> can process Webform submissions
> lets you add your own custom aggregation functions
> ```
>
> ... and it puts summary statistics at the bottom of your aggregated
>   table as well! Recap: what is aggregation again?
>
> In the context of Views tables and this module, aggregation is the
>   process of grouping and compressing result rows on the identical
>   values of one column, while at the same time applying "summary"
>   (aggregation) functions on other columns. For example, you can group
>   the result set on a taxonomy term, so that all rows sharing the same
>   value of the taxonomy column are represented as single rows, with
>   aggregation functions like COUNT, ENUMERATE or SUM applied to the
>   remaining columns. Example
>
> Say the original View based on raw database results looks like below.
>   Industry  Company Name    Turnover IT     AquiB   $  25,000,000 Clothing
>     Cenneton    $  99,000,000 Food  Heiny   $  66,000,000 IT    PreviousBest
>     $    5,000,000 Food     McRonalds   $500,000,000
>
> Then with the grouping taking place on, say Industry, and aggregation
>   functions TALLY, ENUMERATE and SUM applied on Industry, Company Name
>   and Turnover respectively, the final result with a descending sort on
>   the last column will display like below. Note that the module
>   identified three groups. It also added a totals row, Views Calc style.
>   Industry  Companies   Turnover Food (2)   Heiny, McRonalds    $566,000,000
>   Clothing (1)  Cenneton    $  99,000,000 IT (2)    AcquiB, PreviousBest    $ 
>   30,000,000 Totals                 5   $695,000,000
>
> But that's just the beginning. Remember, you can aggregate on Views
>   PHP expressions, so the possibilities are endless! See the README for
>   examples using PHP code snippets.
>
> For the "totals" row you may use the module's Math expression column
>   aggregation function and replacement tokens to calculate a field as,
>   say, the product of two preceding fields.