# Create top 5 of selected options

Tags: views, webforms

I would like to create a top 5 of selected options from a webform.

As users fil in the webform i would like to create a view with the top 5 selections of the list.
How can i do this with views?

Example: i have a webform with 5 options.

a,b,c,d,e

User get a dropdown to choose 1 or multiple options.

When 10 users have filled out the form these are the results

option a is chosen 4 times
option b is chosen 7 times
option c is chosen 2 times
option d is chosen 1 time
option e is chosen 9 times

How can i create a view that show this

Top 5 of selected options:
Option e
Option b
Option a
Option c
Option d

Kind regard Kevin

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view with webform type. Then add a Global PHP field in header.

```
<?php 
$nid=62;
$option1_count=0;
$option2_count=0;
foreach($results as $results1) {
    $each_submission=webform_get_submission($nid, $results1->sid);
    //print_r($each_submission->data);
    if($each_submission->data[1][0]==1) {
        $option1_count++;
    }
    if($each_submission->data[1][0]==2) {
        $option2_count++;
    }
}
$top=[$option1_count,$option2_count];
arsort($top);
?>
```

I haven't tested this code but something like this should work.

**EDIT**:

You can make that code generic but if you don't want that then use grouping and aggregation in views and try [Views Distinct](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_distinct)

First add field Webform submission data:Value(your webform field) and set aggregation to yes. [This](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22037/group-result-and-display-count-in-a-view) will help.

Comment: Isn't is possible with just views? Because with the code its hard coded, in time there wil probably 40 or more options available.
That means every time a new option is added i would have to adjust the code of the view.

Comment: In the example they say "You can create a Contextual Filter for whichever field you want to sort off of. If the filter value is not in the url it will display a list like you have above."

But it seems that i can't make a contextual filter of "Webform submission data: Value (Value1)"